Largest inscribed Circle to solve Bellman's lost-in-a-forest problem
I came across Bellman's lost-in-a-forest problem , which is an unsolved minimization problem in geometry.
According to Wiki , there is a need of a general solution in the form of a geometric algorithm which takes the shape of the forest as input and returns the optimal escape path as the output.
So, suppose we take the circle of largest area that fits inside the shape of the forest, denoted as $C_0$ with radius $r_0$. Now, consider the following strategy for the hiker: if the hiker walks in the direction they are facing with each step tangent to a circle $C_s$ with radius $r_s = r_0+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number.
I believe this is a generic solution for all shapes of forests.
Also, theoretically, the worst-case escape path might be just the circumference of $C_s$.
This is a fairly easy solution, so my question is why is that this is not the solution and why the problem is still unsolved for the generic case?

Consider this Counter-Example :

Let the Circle have Diameter $2$ with radius $1$ , hence Semi-Circle Circumference is $\pi=3.141$ , which is enough to exit that Area in "Worst-Case" , when using OP Algorithm to move around Circle.
That Solution given by OP is not Optimal !
Let the Square (with Side $2$) be slightly extended to give the rectangle (with Sides $2$ & $2+2\Delta$)
My Alternative Algorithm for this is to just go in a Straight line.
Diagonal is "Worst-Case" , though that is just $\sqrt{(2)^2+(2+2\Delta)^2}$
It is around $2\sqrt{2+\cdots} \approx 2\sqrt{2} \approx 2.828$ which is much better !

OP : My question is why is that this is not the Solution
-- Answer : Because it is not the Optimal Solution

OP : Why Problem is still unsolved
-- Answer : Because there are even weirder cases where neither Circle nor Straight line will work , making it necessary to use Spiral & Ellipse & other Curves in general.


